# java.lang.NullPointerException occurrs during startActivity()

Tags: java, android

I'm currently working on my project, and I've got a problem.

My app crashes when it comes to `SearchDic()`.

Here's my code:

```
public int SearchDic(final CharSequence received) {
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run(){
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://m.endic.naver.com/search.nhn?query=" + received + "&searchOption=entryIdiom&preQuery=&forceRedirect="));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }}, 10);
return 0; 
}
```

The service in my app calls this `SearchDic()`, so I used non-static way... such as

```
// Local Variable Received 
MainActivity a = new MainActivity();
a.SearchDic(Received);
```

I've tried Logcat, but it keeps crashing on the `startActivity()` part, and I could see the error message, `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Here's my Logcat Errors:

```
08-17 16:16:10.364: D/AndroidRuntime(19322): Shutting down VM
08-17 16:16:10.364: W/dalvikvm(19322): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c7c1f8)
08-17 16:16:10.369: E/AndroidRuntime(19322): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-17 16:16:10.369: E/AndroidRuntime(19322): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-17 16:16:10.369: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3252)
08-17 16:16:10.369: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3359)
08-17 16:16:10.369: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at com.wjuni.easydic.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:80)
08-17 16:16:10.369: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
08-17 16:16:10.369: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-17 16:16:10.369: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-17 16:16:10.369: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
08-17 16:16:10.369: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-17 16:16:10.369: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-17 16:16:10.369: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
08-17 16:16:10.369: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
08-17 16:16:10.369: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What's problem in my application, and how should I call this function? Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: check if `browserIntent` is `null.`?`

Comment: please post your logcat error, so that we can know where exactly the exception occurs.

Comment: What is the purpose of MainActivity and the Handler? Can you not just create the the intent and startActivity from your service code?

Comment: I tried one, but that crashed as well.

Comment: This, `MainActivity a = new MainActivity();` will **never** give you a functional instance of your main activity. Calling `startActivity(..)` on this instance - which is what will happen when you call `a.SearchDic(Received);` - will never work. You need an actual started activity/context to do stuff like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jens pointed out you should not initialize MainActivity by yourself. 
StartActivity is failing becasue the context of the Activity is not initialized. You need to use your Service's Context. Use below function . Copy this function to your own service.

```
public int SearchDic(final CharSequence received, final Context context) {
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run(){
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://m.endic.naver.com/search.nhn?query=" + received + "&searchOption=entryIdiom&preQuery=&forceRedirect="));
        context.startActivity(browserIntent);
    }}, 10);
return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the browserIntent could be null, else only received is null, that the two points where the null could be init thrown